A limit in a transcendental relationship
$$\sin((\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}{r}+x)\pi)=(\frac{2x}{r\sqrt{x^2+1}}+1)\sin(x\pi),\ 0\le x\le1$$
I'm encountered with this equation when trying to maximise another expression. I want to know  what is the limit of $x$ as $r$ is approaching infinity. I know there must be a limit and it must be below $\frac{1}{2}$. (The background is a little bit complicated and not helpful to this question. But if people are really interested at it, I can show it.)
I tried to plot the equation and it was very flat. I also tried to use Mathematica to numerically solve it and it turned out to be around $0.46163$. I wonder if this is a special number, or else what is its exact form. (I found this number plus one is very close to the $x$ value of local minimum of gamma function on real positive axis, which is $1.4616321...$. However, I don't see any connection between this and gamma function so I hold doubts.)
Mathematica attempt

Here's a path to an equation involving $x$ alone:
Defining
$$p = \frac{2}{r}\sqrt{x^2+1} \qquad q = \frac{2x}{r\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac{px}{x^2+1} \tag1$$
the relation is
$$\begin{align}
(q+1)\sin(x\pi) &= \sin(\;(p+x)\pi\;) \\
&= \sin(p\pi)\cos(x\pi)+\cos(p\pi)\sin(x\pi) \tag2\\[6pt]
\to\quad 
\cot(x\pi) &= \frac{q+1-\cos(p\pi)}{\sin(p\pi)} \tag3\\
&=\frac{q}{\sin(p\pi)}+\frac{2\sin^2(p\pi/2)}{2\sin(p\pi/2)\cos(p\pi/2)} \tag4 \\[4pt]
&=\frac{x}{\pi(x^2+1)}\frac{p\pi}{\sin(p\pi)}+\frac{\sin(p\pi/2)}{\cos(p\pi/2)} \tag5
\end{align}$$
Taking the limit as $r\to\infty$ (and thus $p\to0$) gives
$$\cot(x\pi) \;=\; \frac{x}{\pi(x^2+1)}\lim_{p\to0}\frac{p\pi}{\sin(p\pi)} + 0 \;=\; \frac{x}{\pi(x^2+1)} \tag6
$$
Here's a fun way to write the resulting relation:

$$\tan(x\pi) = \pi\left(x+\frac1x\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

My numerical analysis with Mathematica concurs with OP's finding that $x\approx 0.461630466$. I don't know if this value is special.

A local minimum of the gamma function is at  zmin ≈ +1.46163214496836234126..., so I'm afraid the value is not special - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

The final form in $\tan(x\pi)$ is exactly congruent to what I am investigating. Also the form of $x+\frac{1}{x}$ sort of implies two nodes and a symmetry of $x$ and its inverse, which may give me valuable insight for my studies.

Indeed, this question should not have close relation to gamma function and the number is actually different. However, the important property of this number or to say, this constraint equation, is that $\pm x_0\pm k, k\in \mathbb{N}$ are nearly the other roots, which is congruent to one of the most important property I discovered in my studies.
